# Did Andy Dufresne use more than one rock hammer to escape from Shawshank?

Tags: the-shawshank-redemption

In [Shawshank Redemption](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/), Andrew Dufresne ordered the rock hammer through Red, which he then used for 19 years to pick a hole through the wall.

Did Andy order multiple rock hammers? Its seems impossible to drill a hole for 19 years with one pickaxe.

[image]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Great question! This isn't discussed at any point in the movie, but in the Stephen King novella [Rita Hayworth and Shawshank Redemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rita_Hayworth_and_Shawshank_Redemption) which the movie was based on, Andy **did order multiple rock hammers**. From the [story](http://filmandliterature.edublogs.org/files/2010/08/Rita-Hayworth-And-The-Shawshank-Redemption2.pdf):

> Time continued to pass - the oldest trick in the world, and maybe the
>   only one that  really is magic. But Andy Dufresne had changed. He had
>   grown harder. That's the only  way I can think of to put it. He went
>   on doing Warden Norton's dirty work and he held  onto the library, so
>   outwardly things were about the same. He continued to have his 
>   birthday drinks and his New Year's Eve drinks; he continued to share
>   out the rest of each  bottle. I got him fresh rock-polishing cloths
>   from time to time, *and in 1967 I got him a new  rock-hammer - the one
>   I'd gotten him nineteen years ago had plumb worn out.* Nineteen  years!
>   When you say it sudden like that, those three syllables sound like the
>   thud and  double-locking of a tomb door. The rock-hammer, which had
>   been a ten-dollar item back  then, went for twenty-two by '67. He and
>   I had a sad little grin over that.

Then, from the end of the novella:

> And, of course, he had the rock-hammer. I remember thinking when I got
>   him that  gadget back in '48 that it would take a man six hundred
>   years to burrow through the wall  with it. True enough. *But Andy went
>   right through the wall -even with the soft concrete, it  took him two
>   rock-hammers and twenty-seven years* to hack a hole big enough to get
>   his  slim body through four feet of it.

So in conclusion: **Andy used two rock hammers to escape from the prison**.

Comment: Good find Andrew, I knew one rockhammer was not enough to drill such a big ole

Comment: @Firee If I'm reading things correctly, Andy doesn't receive his second hammer until the same year that he escapes. Essentially he dug almost the entire tunnel using a single hammer.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer it's a bit confused, but apparently he takes 27 years to escape, and the first hammer breaks after 19 years.

Comment: @Lohoris Are you sure? [Google says](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+long+was+andy+dufresne+incarcerated&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS430US430&oq=how+long+was+andy+dufresne+incarcerated&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i64.8176j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) (quoted from Wikipedia) says he escapes after 19 years. Or did they change that just for the fil,?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer I'm sure that this is what is written here _"it took him two rock-hammers and twenty-seven years"_, just read up. Accurate or not, no idea.

Comment: @Lohoris After some more research, I've come to the conclusion that the book had details altered when adapted for the cinema. In the movie, Dufresne only uses a single rock hammer and is incarcerated for a shorter duration (among many other differences).

Comment: I've been very late in responding in this thread, but I just wanted to note that after a little research I would agree that the movie alters the timeline of the story. Whereas the book shows him as incarcerated for 27 years, and replacing his first rock hammer after 19 years, the movie appears to show the entire escape taking 19 years.